# Get recipient from ACTION_SEND intent

Tags: android, email, android-intent

In my Android app, i've inserted an ACTION_SEND intent.

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);

    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[] { emailTo });
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_CC, new String[] { emailCC });
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, defaultSubject);
    intent.setType("text/plain");
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, body);
```

Is there a way to get the recipient filled by the user after he sent the mail ?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, sorry. You do not get any results from an `ACTION_SEND` operation, including any changes the user may have made to the recipient list of an email.

Comment: Can I at least know which send method the user picked ? (Email\SMS\ Whatsup etc... )

Comment: @user721577: Not if you are just using `startActivity()` with the `Intent`. If you create your own "chooser", using `PackageManager` and `queryIntentActivities()`, then you can find out what the user chooses, because the list of candidates is in a `ListView` (or whatever) that *you* created that is in *your* app. If you let the OS handle all of that, it is much easier to code, but you have no way of finding out what the user did, if anything.